# simulate a keypress using sendmessage

Tags: vb.net

I want simulate a keypress but i have small problem.. What i do with hexadecimal ... its not even working :D Here is where i get that virtual-key hexadecimal: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Here is my code:

```
  <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
  Private Shared Function SendMessage2( _
  ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, _
  ByVal wMsg As Integer, _
  ByVal wParam As Integer, _
  <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lParam As String) As Integer
  End Function

SendMessage2(WindowHandle, 256, 0x0D, 0)
SendMessage2(WindowHandle, 257, 0x0D, 65539)
```

Error:

```
Argument not specified for parameter 'lParam' of 'Private Shared Function SendMessage2(hwnd As System.IntPtr, wMsg As Integer, wParam As Integer, lParam As String) As Integer'.
Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.
Too many arguments to 'Private Shared Function SendMessage2(hwnd As System.IntPtr, wMsg As Integer, wParam As Integer, lParam As String) As Integer'.
```

Comment: i though it was just. SendKeys.send(Keys.%)

Comment: I send this to windows alert that is in backround

Comment: is sendmessage2 your own function?

Comment: nope.. i find it on internet

Comment: you blinded? its there already

Comment: can you link me to where you found the function

Comment: somewhere but its needed that function works fine.. only my problem is that hexadecimal.. whats correct integer i need put

Comment: i posted an answer and tested it. If it is helpful please click the check box

Comment: It is strange that this code doesn't give an error. The function is `SendMessage` not `SendMessage2`. `SendMessage2` is an alias for `SendMessageA`.

Comment: Yeah xd I changed it to sendmessage -> dont give error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way to synthesize a keystroke is using the [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, I did an Helper Class to send a Keystroke in a simple way (it needs to be extended for use special chars as string like Ñ or Ç).

Example usages:

```
AppActivate(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").First.Id)

Dim c As Char = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Oemtilde) ' Ñ
Dim Result As Integer = SendInputs.SendKey(Convert.ToChar(c.ToString.ToLower))
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Successfull events: {0}", CStr(Result)))

SendInputs.SendKey(Keys.Enter)
SendInputs.SendKey(Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back))
SendInputs.SendKeys("Hello World", True)
SendInputs.SendKey(Convert.ToChar(Keys.D0))
SendInputs.SendKeys(Keys.Insert, BlockInput:=True)

SendInputs.MouseClick(SendInputs.MouseButton.RightPress, False)
SendInputs.MouseMove(5, -5)
SendInputs.MousePosition(New Point(100, 500))
```

Here is the partial Class where I've removed the MouseInput methods, if you want to see the full class then [go this link](http://foro.elhacker.net/net/libreria_de_snippets_compartan_aqui_sus_snippets-t378770.0.html;msg1921592#msg1921592).

```
' ***********************************************************************
' Author   : Elektro
' Modified : 02-21-2014
' ***********************************************************************
' <copyright file="SendInputs.vb" company="Elektro Studios">
'     Copyright (c) Elektro Studios. All rights reserved.
' </copyright>
' ***********************************************************************

#Region " Imports "

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.ComponentModel

#End Region

''' <summary>
''' Synthesizes keystrokes, mouse motions, and button clicks.
''' </summary>
Public Class SendInputs

#Region " P/Invoke "

   Friend Class NativeMethods

#Region " Methods "

       ''' <summary>
       ''' Blocks keyboard and mouse input events from reaching applications.
       ''' For more info see here:
       ''' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
       ''' </summary>
       ''' <param name="fBlockIt">
       ''' The function's purpose.
       ''' If this parameter is 'TRUE', keyboard and mouse input events are blocked.
       ''' If this parameter is 'FALSE', keyboard and mouse events are unblocked.
       ''' </param>
       ''' <returns>
       ''' If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
       ''' If input is already blocked, the return value is zero.
       ''' </returns>
       ''' <remarks>
       ''' Note that only the thread that blocked input can successfully unblock input.
       ''' </remarks>
       <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall,
       SetLastError:=True)>
       Friend Shared Function BlockInput(
              ByVal fBlockIt As Boolean
       ) As Integer
       End Function

       ''' <summary>
       ''' Synthesizes keystrokes, mouse motions, and button clicks.
       ''' For more info see here:
       ''' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
       ''' </summary>
       ''' <param name="nInputs">
       ''' Indicates the number of structures in the pInputs array.
       ''' </param>
       ''' <param name="pInputs">
       ''' Indicates an Array of 'INPUT' structures.
       ''' Each structure represents an event to be inserted into the keyboard or mouse input stream.
       ''' </param>
       ''' <param name="cbSize">
       ''' The size, in bytes, of an 'INPUT' structure.
       ''' If 'cbSize' is not the size of an 'INPUT' structure, the function fails.
       ''' </param>
       ''' <returns>
       ''' The function returns the number of events that it successfully
       ''' inserted into the keyboard or mouse input stream.
       ''' If the function returns zero, the input was already blocked by another thread.
       ''' </returns>
       <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
       Friend Shared Function SendInput(
              ByVal nInputs As Integer,
              <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), [In]> ByVal pInputs As INPUT(),
              ByVal cbSize As Integer
       ) As Integer
       End Function

#End Region

#Region " Enumerations "

       ''' <summary>
       ''' VirtualKey codes.
       ''' </summary>
       Friend Enum VirtualKeys As Short

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The Shift key.
           ''' VK_SHIFT
           ''' </summary>
           SHIFT = &H10S

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The DEL key.
           ''' VK_DELETE
           ''' </summary>
           DELETE = 46S

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The ENTER key.
           ''' VK_RETURN
           ''' </summary>
           [RETURN] = 13S

       End Enum

       ''' <summary>
       ''' The type of the input event.
       ''' For more info see here:
       ''' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
       ''' </summary>
       <Description("Enumeration used for 'type' parameter of 'INPUT' structure")>
       Friend Enum InputType As Integer

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The event is a keyboard event.
           ''' Use the ki structure of the union.
           ''' </summary>
           Keyboard = 1

       End Enum

       ''' <summary>
       ''' Specifies various aspects of a keystroke.
       ''' This member can be certain combinations of the following values.
       ''' For more info see here:
       ''' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
       ''' </summary>
       <Description("Enumeration used for 'dwFlags' parameter of 'KeyboardInput' structure")>
       <Flags>
       Friend Enum KeyboardInput_Flags As Integer

           ''' <summary>
           ''' If specified, the scan code was preceded by a prefix byte that has the value '0xE0' (224).
           ''' </summary>
           ExtendedKey = &H1

           ''' <summary>
           ''' If specified, the key is being pressed.
           ''' </summary>
           KeyDown = &H0

           ''' <summary>
           ''' If specified, the key is being released.
           ''' If not specified, the key is being pressed.
           ''' </summary>
           KeyUp = &H2

           ''' <summary>
           ''' If specified, 'wScan' identifies the key and 'wVk' is ignored.
           ''' </summary>
           ScanCode = &H8

           ''' <summary>
           ''' If specified, the system synthesizes a 'VK_PACKET' keystroke.
           ''' The 'wVk' parameter must be '0'.
           ''' This flag can only be combined with the 'KEYEVENTF_KEYUP' flag.
           ''' </summary>
           Unicode = &H4

       End Enum

#End Region

#Region " Structures "

       ''' <summary>
       ''' Used by 'SendInput' function
       ''' to store information for synthesizing input events such as keystrokes, mouse movement, and mouse clicks.
       ''' For more info see here:
       ''' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
       ''' </summary>
       <Description("Structure used for 'INPUT' parameter of 'SendInput' API method")>
       <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>
       Friend Structure Input

           ' ******
           '  NOTE
           ' ******
           ' Field offset for 32 bit machine: 4
           ' Field offset for 64 bit machine: 8

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The type of the input event.
           ''' </summary>
           <FieldOffset(0)>
           Public type As InputType

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The information about a simulated mouse event.
           ''' </summary>
           <FieldOffset(8)>
           Public mi As MouseInput

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The information about a simulated keyboard event.
           ''' </summary>
           <FieldOffset(8)>
           Public ki As KeyboardInput

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The information about a simulated hardware event.
           ''' </summary>
           <FieldOffset(8)>
           Public hi As HardwareInput

       End Structure

       ''' <summary>
       ''' Contains information about a simulated mouse event.
       ''' For more info see here:
       ''' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
       ''' </summary>
       <Description("Structure used for 'mi' parameter of 'INPUT' structure")>
       Friend Structure MouseInput

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The absolute position of the mouse,
           ''' or the amount of motion since the last mouse event was generated,
           ''' depending on the value of the dwFlags member.
           ''' Absolute data is specified as the 'x' coordinate of the mouse;
           ''' relative data is specified as the number of pixels moved.
           ''' </summary>
           Public dx As Integer

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The absolute position of the mouse,
           ''' or the amount of motion since the last mouse event was generated,
           ''' depending on the value of the dwFlags member.
           ''' Absolute data is specified as the 'y' coordinate of the mouse;
           ''' relative data is specified as the number of pixels moved.
           ''' </summary>
           Public dy As Integer

           ''' <summary>
           ''' If 'dwFlags' contains 'MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL',
           ''' then 'mouseData' specifies the amount of wheel movement.
           ''' A positive value indicates that the wheel was rotated forward, away from the user;
           ''' a negative value indicates that the wheel was rotated backward, toward the user.
           ''' One wheel click is defined as 'WHEEL_DELTA', which is '120'.
           '''
           ''' If 'dwFlags' does not contain 'MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL', 'MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN', or 'MOUSEEVENTF_XUP',
           ''' then mouseData should be '0'.
           ''' </summary>
           Public mouseData As Integer

           ''' <summary>
           ''' A set of bit flags that specify various aspects of mouse motion and button clicks.
           ''' The bits in this member can be any reasonable combination of the following values.
           ''' The bit flags that specify mouse button status are set to indicate changes in status,
           ''' not ongoing conditions.
           ''' For example, if the left mouse button is pressed and held down,
           ''' 'MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN' is set when the left button is first pressed,
           ''' but not for subsequent motions.
           ''' Similarly, 'MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP' is set only when the button is first released.
           '''
           ''' You cannot specify both the 'MOUSEEVENTF_WHEE'L flag
           ''' and either 'MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN' or 'MOUSEEVENTF_XUP' flags simultaneously in the 'dwFlags' parameter,
           ''' because they both require use of the 'mouseData' field.
           ''' </summary>
           Public dwFlags As MouseInput_Flags

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The time stamp for the event, in milliseconds.
           ''' If this parameter is '0', the system will provide its own time stamp.
           ''' </summary>
           Public time As Integer

           ''' <summary>
           ''' An additional value associated with the mouse event.
           ''' An application calls 'GetMessageExtraInfo' to obtain this extra information.
           ''' </summary>
           Public dwExtraInfo As IntPtr

       End Structure

       ''' <summary>
       ''' Contains information about a simulated keyboard event.
       ''' For more info see here:
       ''' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
       ''' </summary>
       <Description("Structure used for 'ki' parameter of 'INPUT' structure")>
       Friend Structure KeyboardInput

           ''' <summary>
           ''' A virtual-key code.
           ''' The code must be a value in the range '1' to '254'.
           ''' If the 'dwFlags' member specifies 'KEYEVENTF_UNICODE', wVk must be '0'.
           ''' </summary>
           Public wVk As Short

           ''' <summary>
           ''' A hardware scan code for the key.
           ''' If 'dwFlags' specifies 'KEYEVENTF_UNICODE',
           ''' 'wScan' specifies a Unicode character which is to be sent to the foreground application.
           ''' </summary>
           Public wScan As Short

           ''' <summary>
           ''' Specifies various aspects of a keystroke.
           ''' </summary>
           Public dwFlags As KeyboardInput_Flags

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The time stamp for the event, in milliseconds.
           ''' If this parameter is '0', the system will provide its own time stamp.
           ''' </summary>
           Public time As Integer

           ''' <summary>
           ''' An additional value associated with the keystroke.
           ''' Use the 'GetMessageExtraInfo' function to obtain this information.
           ''' </summary>
           Public dwExtraInfo As IntPtr

       End Structure

       ''' <summary>
       ''' Contains information about a simulated message generated by an input device other than a keyboard or mouse.
       ''' For more info see here:
       ''' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
       ''' </summary>
       <Description("Structure used for 'hi' parameter of 'INPUT' structure")>
       Friend Structure HardwareInput

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The message generated by the input hardware.
           ''' </summary>
           Public uMsg As Integer

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The low-order word of the lParam parameter for uMsg.
           ''' </summary>
           Public wParamL As Short

           ''' <summary>
           ''' The high-order word of the lParam parameter for uMsg.
           ''' </summary>
           Public wParamH As Short

       End Structure

#End Region

   End Class

#End Region

#Region " Enumerations "

#End Region

#Region " Public Methods "

   ''' <summary>
   ''' Sends a keystroke.
   ''' </summary>
   ''' <param name="key">
   ''' Indicates the keystroke to simulate.
   ''' </param>
   ''' <param name="BlockInput">
   ''' If set to <c>true</c>, the keyboard and mouse are blocked until the keystroke is sent.
   ''' </param>
   ''' <returns>
   ''' The function returns the number of events that it successfully inserted into the keyboard input stream.
   ''' If the function returns zero, the input was already blocked by another thread.
   ''' </returns>
   Public Shared Function SendKey(ByVal key As Char,
                                  Optional BlockInput As Boolean = False) As Integer

       ' Block Keyboard and mouse.
       If BlockInput Then NativeMethods.BlockInput(True)

       ' The inputs structures to send.
       Dim Inputs As New List(Of NativeMethods.INPUT)

       ' The current input to add into the Inputs list.
       Dim CurrentInput As New NativeMethods.INPUT

       ' Determines whether a character is an alphabetic letter.
       Dim IsAlphabetic As Boolean = Not (key.ToString.ToUpper = key.ToString.ToLower)

       ' Determines whether a character is an uppercase alphabetic letter.
       Dim IsUpperCase As Boolean =
           (key.ToString = key.ToString.ToUpper) AndAlso Not (key.ToString.ToUpper = key.ToString.ToLower)

       ' Determines whether the CapsLock key is pressed down.
       Dim CapsLockON As Boolean = My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock

       ' Set the passed key to upper-case.
       If IsAlphabetic AndAlso Not IsUpperCase Then
           key = Convert.ToChar(key.ToString.ToUpper)
       End If

       ' If character is alphabetic and is UpperCase and CapsLock is pressed down,
       ' OrElse character is alphabetic and is not UpperCase and CapsLock is not pressed down,
       ' OrElse character is not alphabetic.
       If (IsAlphabetic AndAlso IsUpperCase AndAlso CapsLockON) _
       OrElse (IsAlphabetic AndAlso Not IsUpperCase AndAlso Not CapsLockON) _
       OrElse (Not IsAlphabetic) Then

           ' Hold the character key.
           With CurrentInput
               .type = NativeMethods.InputType.Keyboard
               .ki.wVk = Convert.ToInt16(CChar(key))
               .ki.dwFlags = NativeMethods.KeyboardInput_Flags.KeyDown
           End With : Inputs.Add(CurrentInput)

           ' Release the character key.
           With CurrentInput
               .type = NativeMethods.InputType.Keyboard
               .ki.wVk = Convert.ToInt16(CChar(key))
               .ki.dwFlags = NativeMethods.KeyboardInput_Flags.KeyUp
           End With : Inputs.Add(CurrentInput)

           ' If character is alphabetic and is UpperCase and CapsLock is not pressed down,
           ' OrElse character is alphabetic and is not UpperCase and CapsLock is pressed down.
       ElseIf (IsAlphabetic AndAlso IsUpperCase AndAlso Not CapsLockON) _
       OrElse (IsAlphabetic AndAlso Not IsUpperCase AndAlso CapsLockON) Then

           ' Hold the Shift key.
           With CurrentInput
               .type = NativeMethods.InputType.Keyboard
               .ki.wVk = NativeMethods.VirtualKeys.SHIFT
               .ki.dwFlags = NativeMethods.KeyboardInput_Flags.KeyDown
           End With : Inputs.Add(CurrentInput)

           ' Hold the character key.
           With CurrentInput
               .type = NativeMethods.InputType.Keyboard
               .ki.wVk = Convert.ToInt16(CChar(key))
               .ki.dwFlags = NativeMethods.KeyboardInput_Flags.KeyDown
           End With : Inputs.Add(CurrentInput)

           ' Release the character key.
           With CurrentInput
               .type = NativeMethods.InputType.Keyboard
               .ki.wVk = Convert.ToInt16(CChar(key))
               .ki.dwFlags = NativeMethods.KeyboardInput_Flags.KeyUp
           End With : Inputs.Add(CurrentInput)

           ' Release the Shift key.
           With CurrentInput
               .type = NativeMethods.InputType.Keyboard
               .ki.wVk = NativeMethods.VirtualKeys.SHIFT
               .ki.dwFlags = NativeMethods.KeyboardInput_Flags.KeyUp
           End With : Inputs.Add(CurrentInput)

       End If ' UpperCase And My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock is...

       ' Send the input key.
       Return NativeMethods.SendInput(Inputs.Count, Inputs.ToArray,
                                      Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(NativeMethods.Input)))

       ' Unblock Keyboard and mouse.
       If BlockInput Then NativeMethods.BlockInput(False)

   End Function

   ''' <summary>
   ''' Sends a keystroke.
   ''' </summary>
   ''' <param name="key">
   ''' Indicates the keystroke to simulate.
   ''' </param>
   ''' <param name="BlockInput">
   ''' If set to <c>true</c>, the keyboard and mouse are blocked until the keystroke is sent.
   ''' </param>
   ''' <returns>
   ''' The function returns the number of events that it successfully inserted into the keyboard input stream.
   ''' If the function returns zero, the input was already blocked by another thread.
   ''' </returns>
   Public Shared Function SendKey(ByVal key As Keys,
                                  Optional BlockInput As Boolean = False) As Integer

       Return SendKey(Convert.ToChar(key), BlockInput)

   End Function

   ''' <summary>
   ''' Sends a string.
   ''' </summary>
   ''' <param name="String">
   ''' Indicates the string to send.
   ''' </param>
   ''' <param name="BlockInput">
   ''' If set to <c>true</c>, the keyboard and mouse are blocked until the keystroke is sent.
   ''' </param>
   ''' <returns>
   ''' The function returns the number of events that it successfully inserted into the keyboard input stream.
   ''' If the function returns zero, the input was already blocked by another thread.
   ''' </returns>
   Public Shared Function SendKeys(ByVal [String] As String,
                                   Optional BlockInput As Boolean = False) As Integer

       Dim SuccessCount As Integer = 0

       ' Block Keyboard and mouse.
       If BlockInput Then NativeMethods.BlockInput(True)

       For Each c As Char In [String]
           SuccessCount += SendKey(c, BlockInput:=False)
       Next c

       ' Unblock Keyboard and mouse.
       If BlockInput Then NativeMethods.BlockInput(False)

       Return SuccessCount

   End Function

#End Region

End Class
```

Comment: AppActivate(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").First.Id) gives error: 'First' is not a member of 'System.Array'. Ok forgot used framework 2.0.. lol

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing in a hexadecimal, in VB.NET every hexadecimal starts with `&H` followed by everything after the `0x`

So your `SendMessage2(WindowHandle, 256, 0x0D, 0)` needs to be `SendMessage2(WindowHandle, 256, &H0D, 0)`

The hexadecimal is the key you want to send. By changing that you change the key you are sending to the window.

Comment: yea because its the same thing